# Editing a file inside an archive

Tags: compression, zip, archiving, file-archiver

Are there other programs that allow you to edit a file inside an archived file?

For example, 7-zip allows you to edit the file inside the archive. But it changes the compression of the other files (i.e. the file size of the archived file changes drastically).

I want to maintain the compression level the same, as much as possible, while only editing the specific file.

I have tried to use winrar, open the file and edit it externally. However, upon saving, winrar does not update the file.

Comment: The size of the archive will change no matter which program you'll use.

Comment: @montonero even if it is just a minor edit? I'm talking about a large change in size.

Comment: The large change could be due to different compression settings between original compressor and 7-zip. Why is the size so important?